# ES6 class super() with variadic arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, subclass

In ES6, is there a way to call a parent constructor passing through variadic arguments, a la `foo.apply(this, arguments)`? I've looked for an answer, and the only instances I see are either calling `super()` (no arguments) or calling `super(x, y)` (with specific arguments). `super.apply(this, arguments)` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: The spread operator is a better apply.

Comment: `super.constructor.apply(this, arguments)` would work if `this` was already initialised

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The pattern I find convenient and follow is

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

In case you have and use named arguments you could do this instead:

```
constructor(a, b, c) {
    super(...arguments);
}
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator
- https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: If you are using this in a browser, just be aware of spread operator support as support is fairly new and for some reason support for the spread operator came later than other ES6 features such as `class`.  For example, I don't think there's any IE support.  You could, of course, also use a transpiler.

Comment: @jfriend00 IE does not support almost anything from ES2015, so, who cares :-)

Comment: It's easy to find versions of Chrome in use that aren't the latest and support `class`, but don't support the spread operator.  I'm just advising the OP to make sure they have the browser support they need.  Don't get so defensive.  This is a nice answer if your environment supports it.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the use of the spread operator as an apply, that's very handy. Thanks!