# spread syntax in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extend a class in an Angular project and I want to pass arguments to the parent class using the rest/spread syntax of ES2015 like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447168/es6-class-super-with-variadic-arguments)

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

but I get an error `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target` and my app won't compile.

I made [a contrived example using the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PersonGreeter%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F*%20This%20doesn't%20work%0D%0Aclass%20PersonGreeter%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PersonGreeter%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20PersonGreeter(%22Mr.%20Smith%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet(salutation%3A%20string%20%3D%20'Hello')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20salutation%20%2B%20%22%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20doesn't%20work%0D%0Aclass%20PersonGreeter%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20super.greet(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20PersonGreeter(%22Mr.%20Smith%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B). Does anyone know how to get this to work without having to explicitly write the arguments of the parent class methods?

UPDATE: As pointed out by Teddy Sterne I actually don't need to use this for the constructor because it has the same arguments. I actually want to use this for a method that returns an observable. I want to catch errors by overriding the method and returning super.parentMethod(...args).catch(/* deal with error */)

Comment: The `Greeter` constructor takes in a `string`, passing an `any[]` array into a function expecting a `string` isn't expected to work. What are you trying to do?

Comment: https://es6console.com/j4rasbut/ this works in ES6 but not in typescript. I guess it's because of the type checking?

Comment: Does it work if you just do `super(args)`?

Comment: @Paarth he's not passing an array into the super. He's forwarding the function parameters. I suspect this is a TypeScript limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be to use the built-in `ConstructorParameters` Type Helper.

```
class A {
    constructor (foo: number, bar: string) {}
}


class B extends A {
    constructor (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof A>) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked and answered in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11679

You are correct assuming it's because of type checking. Lets assume the parent constructor expects a fixed number of parameters. At the point `super(...args)` is declared, the compiler doesn't know the actual number of passed parameters. Therefore it flags it as unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Child` has the exact same parameters to the constructor as the `Parent` then you do not need to specify the constructor. The dependencies will be injected that are required by the parent and the parent's constructor will be call implicitly.

```js
class ParentClass {
    constructor(dep1: Dep1, dep2: Dep2) { }
}

class ChildClass {

}
```

If the child has additional dependencies then you will have to re-specify them and then pass them to the Parent's constructor inside the Child's constructor.

```js
class ParentClass {
    constructor(dep1: Dep1, dep2: Dep2) { }
}

class ChildClass {
    constructor(dep1: Dep1, dep2: Dep2, dep3: Dep3) {
        super(dep1, dep2);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are correct, I actually don't need to use this for the constructor rather for a method that returns an observable. I want to catch errors by overriding the method and returning super.parentMethod(...args).catch(/* deal with error */)